# Specflow scenarios with NUnit test parameters

Tags: selenium, nunit, bdd, specflow

When using NUnit, you can pass in parameters to your tests using TestCaseSourceAttribute.

```
[Test, TestCaseSource(typeof(WebDriverFactory), "Drivers")]
```

What would be the best approach to doing the same for tests generated using specflow? Those tests do not use the 'Test' attribute. They use 'Given', 'And', 'Then' etc.

I'm trying to pass in different web drivers (selenium) so I don't have to manually change them to test across different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Specflow creates automatically test fixtures, so you cannot use `[TestCaseSource]`. You can try [Test class generator to drive automated web ui tests with Selenium and SpecFlow](https://github.com/baseclass/Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit).

However you should ask yourself if executing Specflow scenarios in different browsers brings a lot of benefits to your project, as execution time of your acceptance tests will double/triple. From my experience cross browser testing identifies UI changes and very rare functional (to be honest I've never encountered any). In our team testers perform it manually.